# Convert a <span>'s text into a hyperlink

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

UPDATE:
Answer #3 ended up working the best.  I most likely did something wrong with the other suggestions; #3 was maybe the easiest to implement.  If you are curious, the example solutions that I tried can be found here (for now):

1. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1007716/spanToUrl/test01.html
2. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1007716/spanToUrl/test02.html
3. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1007716/spanToUrl/test03.html (winner)
4. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1007716/spanToUrl/test04.html
5. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1007716/spanToUrl/test05.html
6. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1007716/spanToUrl/test06.html

ORIGINAL POST:
I have a plain text website address inside a `<span>` tag.  I'd like to change that <span> tag into a proper hyperlink with `target="_blank"`

I've put together a detailed example of what I have to work with here: http://bit.ly/spantourl

If you don't want to click through, here is what I have:

```
<span>http://www.domain.com/about</span>
```

and I need to change that into:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/about" target="_blank">http://www.domain.com/about</a>
```

Comment: Can you add a class to the output span?

Comment: no, but I can wrap the output span in another span with a class so that it would be <span class="myClass"><span>http://www.domain.com/about</span></span>

Comment: no need for classes/ids -  use a for-each loop on the specific element

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.sampleClass span').replaceWith(function() {
    var url = $.trim($(this).text());
    return '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">' + url + '</a>';
});
```

There's no need for `each`, since replaceWith can iterate through multiple elements and can take a function as a parameter.

Looking at your sample HTML, I see that it is only the first `<td>` that contains a URL. If there is indeed only one, you can add `first()` to the selector chain, like this:

```
$('.sampleClass span').first().replaceWith( /* ... */ );
```

If it is rather the entire *column* that contains links, than you'll want to operate on every other match. Do this by appending `:even` to your selector, like this:

```
$('.sampleClass span:even').first().replaceWith( /* ... */ );
```

(Yes, `:even` and not `:odd` to select the 1st, 3rd, &c. elements, because of 0-based indexing.)

Comment: I love learning from other "competing" answers. I say, jolly good ol' chap.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the good cheer. I agree: seeing multiple implementations side-by-side is one of the best things about this site.

Comment: Also took a shot at this one, here:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1007716/spanToUrl/test03.html

No luck getting that to work either.

Comment: You're placing the code before the actual HTML, so $('.sampleClass span') returns an empty set, since the elements you're looking for don't exist yet. Try to move that script block to the end of the BODY tag.

Comment: oops, OK, taking another shot with script at the bottom of the page.  Thanks for looking - this will likely fix the other ones I broke too.

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1007716/spanToUrl/test03.html seems to be the winner - not the most elegant, but it is the one that is resulting in what I need.

Comment: Alternately, attach the function to the onload event of the window object, so that it only executes once the page is finished loading. See here http://dpaste.com/481035/ (with the :even selector)

Comment: the even odd approach won't work - urls can appear anywhere.  Also, I am pretty sure the CMS has problems with the window object, but I am going to test your suggestion out for my own personal learning.

Comment: OK, so #3 ended up working for me.  It may not be the best solution, but it works.  Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Put the span an id and then you can do something like

```
var linkText = $("#yourspanid").text();

$("<a/>").attr({"href": linkText, "target": "_blank"}).text(linkText).appendTo("body");
$("#yourspanid").remove();
```

Changing according to your edit

```
var elems = $("span.myClass > span");
elems.each(function(){
    var linkText= $(this).text();
    $("<a/>").attr({"href": linkText, "target": "_blank"}).text(linkText).appendTo("body");
});
elems.remove();
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MrTTz/)

Comment: probably jacking this one up like all of the others, but this is not working form e either, see here:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1007716/spanToUrl/test05.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to have some form of identification in order to do the conversion from node A to node B. I would suggest something along the following lines:

The JQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.convertableIdentifier').each(function(i, el) {

        // grab the url and the link text
        var url = $(el).html();

        // create a new node with query by decorating a
        // empty a tag
        var newNode = $('<a></a>').attr('href', url).attr('target', '_blank').html(url);

        // replace the current node with our new node
        $(el).replaceWith(newNode);

    });

</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<span class="convertableIdentifier">http://www.google.com</span>
<span class="convertableIdentifier">http://www.youtube.com</span>
<span class="convertableIdentifier">http://www.facebook.com</span>
```

The above code is not tested, but should hopefully lead you in the right direction.

Comment: `.replaceWith()` can iterate through a set, so there's no need to wrap it in `each`. See my answer.

Comment: Took a shot here:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1007716/spanToUrl/test01.html

No luck getting it to work on my page even though it worked on jsfiddle, here: http://jsfiddle.net/GyK3q/

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery.

give the span an id:

```
<span id="linkChange">http://domain.com</span>
```

jQuery code:

```
var href = jQuery('#linkChange').html();
var link = "<a href='"+href+"' target='_blank'>"+href+"</a>";

jQuery('#linkChange').replaceWith(link);
```

Comment: No luck, tried this solution out here:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1007716/spanToUrl/test04.html

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this: (no need to know ids/classes) useing jquerys for-each loop and specificly target spans inside of tds

<strike>$(document).ready(function(){
            $('td span').each(function(){
                $(this).text("" + 
                    $(this).text() + "");
            });
        });</strike>

## EDIT:this code works much better:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('td span').each(function(){
            $(this).html("<a href='" + $(this).html() + "' />" + 
                $(this).html() + "</a>");
        });
    });
</script>
```

The origional used the `.text()` function of jquery which html escaped the `<>` characters, unintentionally addin `&GT; &LT;` into the dom, while .html actually outputs the correct tags

Comment: Wow, love this community.  How is a newb to choose with so many potential answers?  Thank yo for the jsfiddle link - forgot about that site.  I am not sure which answer is best, I will test a few in the CMS and see if it works.

Comment: i double nested and modified the script to reflect the double span, and it is close to working, but the output is not quite right.  The single quotes seem to need to be double quotes for it to work.  See here:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1007716/spanToUrl/test02.html

Comment: Wonderful, glad to see its close to working for you! Whenever you do get it working, don't forget to mark-as-answer which ever answer helped the most!

Comment: Answer marked, took some testing to determine which was best.  The edited code above did work too, but it produces some invalid HTML.  The example can be seen here:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1007716/spanToUrl/test06.html